# Is there a htop-on-linux like alternative for top / Activity Monitor on OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, activity-monitor, macos

I'm looking for a better alternative for *top*. Both *top* and *Activity Monitor* are highly limited with regards to features. In particular, I'm interested in the following features:

- Limit processes by name
- Send different kill-signals to a process interactively, i.e. select the process from the process list and send a signal
- Ability to show the entire command, not only the program name (as `top -c` does on Linux)
- Show the status of each process
- Optional: On Linux, *top* also *updates* the command when displayed, i.e. if a process writes in it's own `argv` during runtime, the updated command will be shown.

Htop is not an option, as it is unstable on Mac OS and only a small subset of it's features actually works on a Darwin system, probably because it partially relies on procfs. Is there a build or fork of htop that works on OS X since it has the features I want if it worked as it does on Linux?

Answer (score 5):

You can install htop on Mac through [brew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) with the following command:

`brew install htop-osx`

Don' t forget to grant root privileges after the installation.

Comment: Or with macports `sudo port install htop`

Comment: As I said, htop is *not* an option. It's features very limited on Mac OS X, most of them simply don't work.

Comment: What is this "grant root privileges" you refer to? Anyway seems that htop these days supports more on OS X, so this is a good option...

Answer (score 1):

Sending of signals and filtering by user is available out of the box. From `man top`

```
   INTERACTION
          When top is run in interactive (non-logging) mode, it is possible to control the output of top, as well as  in-
          teractively  send  signals to processes.  The interactive command syntax is terse.  Each command is one charac-
          ter, followed by 0 to 2 arguments.

   S<signal><pid>
          Send <sig> to <pid>.  <sig> can be specified either as a number or as a name (for example, HUP).   The  default
          signal  starts  out as TERM.  Each time a signal is successfully sent, the default signal is updated to be that
          signal.  <pid> is a process id.

   U<user>
          Only display processes owned by <user>.  Either the username or uid number can be specified.   To  display  all
          processes, press enter without entering a username or uid number.
```

If you want to extend `top` yourself, the source code is available on http://opensource.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I'm aware of that "feature"... however, specifying a signal *and* a PID is not really what counts as interactive... there is not improved comfort over writing "kill" on the commandline. I mean, the process should be selectable *interactively* (as in htop)

Answer (score 1):

You can use process explorer for OS X - http://newosxbook.com/ has that as a free download. It's modeled after Linux top, and is much more powerful than Apple's own.

Comment: 1. Could you link directly to the download. 2. Be sure to read over the [help] on promotion.